# Sprite icon in Grid

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to render a Sprite icon instead of plain text in a custom unbound field. Here is what I have done.

```
public class ContractDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CT.ContractDetail>
{
    #region UsrLinkToContractLneItemDetails

    [PXString(50)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Details", Enabled = false)]
    [PXImage(HeaderImage = "main@Info")]
    [PXUnboundDefault("main@Info", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string UsrLinkToContractLneItemDetails { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrLinkToContractLneItemDetails : IBqlField { }

    #endregion
}
```

And here is the properties set

[image]

And this is how the screen looks.

[image]

I would appreciate the help if you point out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting DisplayMode="Value", the default is likely Text so I was able to get your code working by changing that property.
[image]

Result:
[image]

As Bikash Lama found out, 'LinkCommand' property seems incompatible with Value display mode.

Project XML Items:

```
<Customization level="0" description="" product-version="17.208">
    <Page path="~/pages/so/so301000.aspx" pageSource="..."
        <PXGridLevel DataMember="Transactions" ParentId="phG_tab_Items#0_grid_Levels#0" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridLevel">
            <Children Key="Columns">
                <AddItem>
                    <PXGridColumn TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
                        <Prop Key="DataField" Value="UsrLinkToContractLneItemDetails" />
                        <Prop Key="Width" Value="200" />
                        <Prop Key="DisplayMode" Value="Value" />
                        <Prop Key="Type" Value="Icon" />
                    </PXGridColumn>
                </AddItem>
            </Children>
        </PXGridLevel>
    </Page>
    <DAC type="PX.Objects.SO.SOLine">
        <Field FieldName="UsrLinkToContractLneItemDetails" TypeName="string" TextAttributes="#CDATA" StorageName="AddColumn">
            <CDATA name="TextAttributes"><![CDATA[[PXString(50)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Details", Enabled = false)]
[PXImage(HeaderImage = "main@Info")]
[PXUnboundDefault("main@Info", PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]]]></CDATA>
        </Field>
    </DAC>
</Customization>
```

Comment: I changed the DisplayMode to 'Value' but not luck.

Comment: I added project item XML from my test project so you can compare with your own. I think you're having issue refreshing your website. Try removing the column from the grid and adding it again using defaults settings then set DisplayMode="Value", Type="Icon" then publish, then IISReset. If it shows empty, debug and make sure value in field is actually "main@Info".

Comment: I see, the problem was LinkCommand property. When I added this  ViewContractLineItemDetails in 'LinkCommand' it renders as a link text, but when I remove that, it works perfectly.

Comment: Alright, I have added this information to my answer. If you need it to be clickable I think you can look into having a Button Image type or using javascript.

Comment: Here I added a Javascript control. But I am finding hard to integrate that script with the Details column in grid to execute the Command selected.

https://imgur.com/a/1UN49PP

Comment: I managed to execute the javascript function on Cell Click event. Now, how do I call the Action method of Graph from javascript?

Comment: px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("action"); 'action' is case sensitive. If my answer worked for you, you can mark it as accepted, green checkmark.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and it simply calls the function. Now the problem is before the code to get the current Contract Detail was working as I have set the SyncPosition to true of grid and that would set the current contract detail. But, now it is executing the ClientEvent first (opening up window) and then setting the selected Contract Detail as Current. The code is in below comment.

Comment: `public PXAction<Contract> viewContractLineItemDetails;
 [PXButton]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewContractLineItemDetails(PXAdapter adapter)
{
            CustomContractLineItemDetailMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomContractLineItemDetailMaint>();
            var currentContractDetail = Base.ContractDetails.Cache.Current as ContractDetail;
            graph.MasterView.Current = currentContractDetail;
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Contract Line Item Details") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
}`

Comment: Put your action on a PXButton that is part of the grid toolbar with DependOnGrid="grid" property of PXDSCallbackCommand where 'grid' is the id of your grid then call that action.

Comment: You mean like, instead of this 
px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("action")

I replace the ds with the id of grid?

Comment: No, I mean SyncPosition="true" and DependOnGrid="grid"  where 'grid' is the ID of your ContractDetails grid are required for setting the current. Also put the button in the grid toolbar and test it. If it works with the button then it should work when invoking the button action or calling the button click handler.

Comment: You can refer to this post for setting the current of the grid: http://blog.zaletskyy.com/dependongrid-in-acumatica-or-how-to-get-currently-selected-record-in-grid

Comment: Changed the DependOnGrid="detGrid" (ID of ContractDetails Grid) and tried adding the Action on Grid Toolbar too. But both of the trick didn't work.
https://imgur.com/a/79y8unr
https://imgur.com/a/7NCUvE6

Comment: The example in your screenshots are substantially different from the one in the blog post I linked to. I suggest you double check and follow the instructions as close as possible.